# HttpRequest.ServerVariables vs HttpRequest.UserAgent Properties VB.net

Tags: vb.net, httprequest, user-agent

What would be the difference (if any) and advantages/disadvantages between these two properties used to determine the user agent?

```
Dim strUserAgt as String
userAgent = Request.userAgent
```

vs.

```
Dim strUserAgt as String = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: [How to determine browser type in server-side code without the BrowserType object in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306576)

> In ASP.NET, you can access the Request.ServerVariables collection or
>   use the new Request.UserAgent property to retrieve the HTTP_USER_AGENT
>   header value.

There are no difference, both will retrieve same thing `HTTP_USER_AGENT header value`.

Check [Request.ServerVariables Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) if you want to dig it in deep. These server variables collection values somewhat depend ond the IIS version also.

Comment: So then I would assume that this applies to gathering another server variable such as query_string? What about a variable that doesn't have it's own property such as server_port, are you then required to use the ServerVariables property?

Comment: And also, what is the reason for only some server variables having their own property to be determined, but not all? Sorry to bombard you with questions.

Comment: Port, query string, host, path, scheme, etc are part of the `HttpContext.Request.Url` object. Have a look at the `HttpRequest` object docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties(v=vs.100).aspx.