# Issue between HttpRequest.ServerVariables["http_user_agent"] vs HttpRequest.UserAgent

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
<p>
    <b>You are browsing this site with:</b>
    <% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["http_user_agent"]); %>
    <br/>
    <b>Or with Request.UserAgent:</b>
    <% Request.UserAgent.Trim(); %>
</p>
```

The first one is shown correctly in the browser but the second one (`Request.UserAgent`) is not showing. Why? Also If I write the second one in the `Page_Load` method in the code behind it works fine. Why the second one works in `Page_Load` but not in the `p` tag. Also based on Microsoft and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472820/httprequest-servervariables-vs-httprequest-useragent-properties-vb-net) answer the both of them should be same:

> In ASP.NET, you can access the Request.ServerVariables collection or use the new Request.UserAgent property to retrieve the HTTP_USER_AGENT header value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, both will return the same text. But you have missed the `Response.Write` in your second code, Try as below

```
<p>
    <b>You are browsing this site with:</b>
    <% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["http_user_agent"]); %>
    <br/>
    <b>Or with Request.UserAgent:</b>
    <% Response.Write(Request.UserAgent.Trim()); %>
</p>
```